# Polymorphic ID does not accept external ID, or does it?

Tags: data-loader, externalid, polymorphism, polymorphic

**Requirement:**
Via APEX dataloader upload attachments (standard object) and link it via ParentId to a custom object's record. This works easily when the SFDC ID is provided for the polymorphic ParentId on attachment object. This does not seem to work using an external ID.

**But!** There seems to be a way, as per SFDC [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/datafiles_csv_rel_field_header_row.htm).

However, I can't get this to work by using the APEX dataloader.

**Question:** can anyone get this to work via dataloader (because that is the requirement)? If so, what's the trick?
I can also imagine, this does not function via the dataloader, but it does work via a custom SOAP or REST API, or potentially using DML statements.

Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: According to your link, that only works with BUlk API. Have you enabled the Bulk API in Data Loader? https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=loader_configuring_bulk_api.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Hi Daniel, I indeed enabled the Bulk API in the data loader settings, but this didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **no**, a lookup is related to a record in your org, and a polymorphic lookup is not different

Long answer:

Polymorphic lookups are Salesforce **internal** lookups to any kind of object, or a restricted list of objects. You can configure which records you can relate to events, checking the field "Track Activities" in a custom object for example. The id that is stored inside, it has to be a Salesforce Id, 18 character long, because it's a **real lookup** to another object, the only problem is you don't know which one.

You can find this kind of relationships in events, opportunities or attachments, but I want to do the same with a custom object I'll not be able to :(

Comment: Attachments are a one-off in data loader land.  You can load custom and other standard objects via external ids (and associate their parents via external ids), but not Attachments.  You might consider a mirrored custom object you can upsert against that handles attachments in a trigger, or more complex, writing a webservice to handle the attachment upload.

Comment: Here's a similar post: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22535/not-able-to-upload-attachments-to-accounts-with-external-id

Comment: Hi Ricard and James, I assumed the same, however the SFDC documentation (link in the question description) says it can be done by using a column header formatting. So, if SFDC says it can be done, I have a feeling it indeed can be done.